# SQLite Insert Data Failure

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Ive created a database that logs and registers and that works fine but when im creating the database to add an income im getting no errors back just the toast message to say failure and i cant understnad why becuase im passing the correct variables through i will attach the code below.

DatabseHelper Code the insertIncome is the one imtrying to insert into here is the code for the class: public class DatabaseHelper  extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

```
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 16;

    //Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "User.db";

    //Table Created
    private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";

    //Columns in Table
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    private static final String COLUMN_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String COLUMN_PASS = "password";
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    private String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + COLUMN_USERNAME + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_PASS + " TEXT " + ")";

    private String DROP_USER_TABLE = " DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER;
    //table created
    private static final String TABLE_INCOME = "income";
    //columns in table
    private static final String COL1 = "id";
    private static final String COL2 = "iAmount";
    private static final String COL3 = "iMethod";
    private static final String COL4 = "date";

    private String CREATE_INCOME_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_INCOME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            " FIRSTNAME TEXT, LASTNAME TEXT, FAVFOOD TEXT)";

    private String DROP_INCOME_TABLE = " DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_INCOME;

    //table created
    private static final String TABLE_EXPENSE = "expense";
    //columns in table
    private static final String COLUMN_EID = "id";
    private static final String COLUMN_EAMOUNT = "eAmount";
    private static final String COLUMN_EMETHOD = "eMethod";
    private static final String COLUMN_EDATE = "date";

    private String CREATE_EXPENSE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EXPENSE + "(" + COLUMN_EID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + COLUMN_EAMOUNT + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_EMETHOD + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_EDATE + "TEXT " + ")";

    private String DROP_EXPENSE_TABLE = " DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_EXPENSE;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_INCOME_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_EXPENSE_TABLE);
        this.db = db;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
       db.execSQL(DROP_USER_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(DROP_INCOME_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(DROP_EXPENSE_TABLE);
        this.onCreate(db);

    }

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public void insertUser(User user){
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        String query = "select * from " + TABLE_USER;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        values.put(COLUMN_ID, count);
        values.put(COLUMN_USERNAME, user.getUsername());
        values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, user.getEmail());
        values.put(COLUMN_PASS, user.getPassword());

        db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
        db.close();
    }
    public boolean insertIncome(int iAmount, String iMethod, String iDate) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL2, iAmount);
        contentValues.put(COL3, iMethod);
        contentValues.put(COL4, iDate);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_INCOME, null, contentValues);

        if(result == -1){
            return false;
        }else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void insertExpense(Income income){


    }
    public String checkUser(String username){
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT username, password from user";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        String a, b;
        b = "error";
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                a = cursor.getString(0);


                if(a.equals(username)){
                    b = cursor.getString(1);
                    break;
                }
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return b;

    }

    public Cursor getList(){
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor query = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_INCOME, null);
        return query;
    }




}
```

The model Class:

public class Income {

```
    public int iAmount;
    public String iMethod;
    public String iDate;

    public Income(int iAmount, String iMethod, String iDate) {
        iAmount = iAmount;
        iMethod = iMethod;
        iDate = iDate;
    }



    public int getiAmount() {
        return iAmount;
    }

    public void setiAmount(int incAmount) {
        this.iAmount = incAmount;
    }

    public String getiMethod() {
        return iMethod;
    }

    public void setiMethod(String iMethod) {
        this.iMethod = iMethod;
    }

    public String getiDate() {
        return iDate;
    }

    public void setDate(String iDate) {
        iDate = iDate;
    }






}
```

the class thats trying to insert data:

```
public class incomePlus extends AppCompatActivity {

    public TextView transactionIncome;
    public Button incomeSubmit;
    public EditText incomeAmount;
    public EditText incomeDate;
    public Spinner Category;
    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_income_plus);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        transactionIncome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.transactionIncome);
        incomeSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.incomeSubmit);
        incomeAmount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.incomeAmount);
        incomeDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.incomeDate);
        Category = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Category);

        List<String> incomeCat = new ArrayList<String>();
        incomeCat.add("Salary");
        incomeCat.add("Lotto");
        incomeCat.add("Gift");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, incomeCat);
        Category.setAdapter(adapter);

        incomeSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                String iAM = incomeAmount.getText().toString();
                int iAmount = Integer.parseInt(iAM);
                String iDate = incomeDate.getText().toString();
                String iMethod = Category.getSelectedItem().toString();

                if (incomeAmount.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && incomeDate.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && Category.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().length() > 0 ) {
                    Intent homeScreen = new Intent(incomePlus.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(homeScreen);

                    addData(iAmount, iMethod, iDate);

                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(incomePlus.this, "Please Fill In All The Fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });



        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_income, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.menuMain : startActivity (new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                break;
        }
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.menuExpense : startActivity (new Intent(this, ExpenseIncome.class));
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void addData(int iAmount, String iMethod, String iDate){
        boolean insertData = db.insertIncome(iAmount, iMethod, iDate);

        if(insertData==true){
            Toast.makeText(incomePlus.this, "Data Entered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(incomePlus.this, "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `comma` at the end of the Create table query.

use:

```
private String CREATE_INCOME_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_INCOME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        " FIRSTNAME TEXT, LASTNAME TEXT, FAVFOOD TEXT);";
```

add comma inside the double quote at end--for all create table query.

Comment: you are welcome..if the answer helps mark it as correct by clicking the tick sign next to the answer...thankx